# TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null

Tags: actionscript

I new with flash and I really don't know what is the reason I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
>   at flash.text::TextField/set text()
>   at sgmap_fla::MainTimeline/mapOver()

my actionscript:

```
description.countryName_txt.text = "";
description.zone_txt.text = "";

map_mc.buttonMode=true;

map_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mapOver);
map_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mapOut);

map_mc.northZone.countryName = "Singapore"; 
map_mc.northZone.zone = "North Zone";

map_mc.centralZone.countryName = "Singapore"; 
map_mc.centralZone.zone = "Central Zone";

map_mc.eastZone.countryName = "Singapore"; 
map_mc.eastZone.zone = "East Zone";

map_mc.westZone.countryName = "Singapore"; 
map_mc.westZone.zone = "West Zone";

map_mc.southZone.countryName = "Singapore"; 
map_mc.southZone.zone = "South Zone";

function mapOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var mapItem:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    description.countryName_txt.text = mapItem.countryName;
    description.zone_txt.text = mapItem.zone;   
    description.gotoAndStop(mapItem.name);
    TweenMax.to(mapItem, .5, {tint:0xFF9900});
    TweenMax.fromTo(description, .5, {alpha:0, x:50, blurFilter:{blurX:80}}, {alpha:1, x:10, blurFilter:{blurX:0}});
    }

function mapOut(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var mapItem:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
    TweenMax.to(mapItem, .5, {tint:0x990000});
    }
```

Comment: Text fields text cannot be set to null.  This could be confirmed by tracing `mapItem` properties of `countryName` and `zone` before setting your textfields: `trace(mapItem.countryName); trace(mapItem.zone);` From your `mapOver` event handler, `mapItem` is seemingly not a zone containing those properties.

Comment: Hi Jason, it doesn't seems working although I changed from:
`description.countryName_txt.text = mapItem.countryName;
description.zone_txt.text = mapItem.zone;`

to

`description.countryName_txt.text = trace(mapItem.countryName);
description.zone_txt.text = trace(mapItem.zone);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text field text cannot be null.

Specifically this error is caused by setting a text field `text` property to `null`.  This can be replicated with `TextField` Classic Text:

Classic Text:

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = null;
```

This will throw the error your cited:

> Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.

TLF Text does not have this issue, and may be set to null.

Per your implementation, this occurs within your `mapOver(e:MouseEvent)` function.  Either `mapItem.countryName` or `mapItem.zone` are null.  It's likely they are both null.

```
var mapItem:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
description.countryName_txt.text = mapItem.countryName; // null
description.zone_txt.text = mapItem.zone;               // null
```

Mouse events do not seem to be dispatched from the scope you expect.  You have a listener on `map_mc`:

```
map_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mapOver);
```

It looks like you're expecting this event from any of the following movie clips: `northZone`, `centralZone`, `eastZone`, `westZone`, and `southZone`.  These symbols have the properties you are looking for; however, map_mc does not.

So, root cause is that your event listener `e.target` is not the symbol you are expecting.

Verify what symbol `e.target` is.  It's probably `map_mc` which does not have the properties you are expecting:

```
map_mc.countryName; // doesn't exist
mac_mc.zone;        // doesn't exist
```

You're looking for those properties on a child of `map_mc`:

```
map_mc.northZone.countryName;
map_mc.northZone.zone;

map_mc.centralZone.countryName;
map_mc.centralZone.zone;

// etc...
```

Comment: hi Jason, I can get what you mean but how suppose for me to code so that I won't have this error? I think you are right because the error only shown after my mouse did not point to the zone which mean out of the map.

Comment: Will this error go away if I initialize like this?`map_mc.countryName = "";
mac_mc.zone= "";`

Comment: Not sure what these zone MovieClips are - first, you could try to attach the event listener directly to zones, as in: `map_mc.northZone.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mapOver);`